# ScrollView always expands to whole Screen

Tags: android, android-layout

Friends,
I have a LinearLayout that contains 3 LinearLayouts. 
1. Headline Linearlayout
2. Content LinearLayout
3. Footer LinearLayout

The 2. Content LinearLayout  gets its content dynamically during runtime. A lot of TextViews gets added. This Layout therefore should be ScrollView.

The problem in my case is, that all the Screen is permanently scrollable instead of only layout 2. Content LinearLayout.

In the Xml theres also a SlidingDrawer that contains a Map, if this might be the cause of the Problem.

Thx for your support, heres part of my code:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="50">

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10" android:src="@drawable/appiconone" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10"  />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10" android:text="" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10" android:text="" />

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10" android:src="@drawable/appiconone" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/LL2Content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="100">

        <Button android:id="@+id/10"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50" android:text="" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/11"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50" android:text="" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try android:scrollbars="none"

Answer (score 0):

just change your ScrollView Height fix like this and also add fillViewport in ScrollView

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="370dp" android:fillViewport="true">
```

I hope this will work for you...

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Use Relative Layout in order to maintain Header, Content and Footer Layout.
Step 2 : Create Header and Footer Layouts and includes in main layout in order to make header and footer reusable. 
Step 3 : Place the Content area below the Header and Above the Footer Layout. 
Step 4 :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:fillViewport="true">
```